# Aggregating payroll data with pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I am working with payroll data and need to aggregate tax data to get current to date, quarter to date, and year to date values. The following is an example of the structure of my data in list of python dictionaries where each item in the dictionary is a paystub with its corresponding taxes and other information. I am using pandas for this and am trying to figure out how exactly I can get to the correct solution.

```
[{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 1,
'check_date' : '01/07/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': 10000.0,
          'FUTA': 0.0,
          'MED': 580.0,
          'MED-R': 580.0,
          'MEDADD': 0.0,
          'NY': 3848.0,
          'NYSUI': 0.0,
          'NYSUR': 0.0,
          'SS': 2480.0,
          'SS-R': 2480.0
         }
},
{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 1,
'check_date' : '01/21/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': 500.0,
          'FUTA': 0.0,
          'MED': 580.0,
          'MED-R': 580.0,
          'MEDADD': 0.0,
          'NY': 3848.0,
          'NYSUI': 0.0,
          'NYSUR': 0.0,
          'SS': 2480.0,
          'SS-R': 2480.0
         }
},
{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 2,
'check_date' : '04/04/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': 500.00,
          'FUTA': 0.0,
          'MED': 580.0,
          'MED-R': 580.0,
          'MEDADD': 0.0,
          'NY': 3848.0,
          'NYSUI': 0.0,
          'NYSUR': 0.0,
          'SS': 2480.0,
          'SS-R': 2480.0}
}]
```

The end result I would like is something structured similar to the following where I can access current to date, quarter to date, and year to date values easily for a given paystub/check date in the list.

```
[{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 1,
'check_date' : '01/07/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': {'ctd' : 10000.0, 'qtd' : 10000.0, 'ytd' : 10000.0},
          'FUTA': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'MED': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 580.0, 'ytd' : 580.0},
          'MED-R': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 580.0, 'ytd' : 580.0},
          'MEDADD': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NY': {'ctd' : 3848.0, 'qtd' : 3848.0, 'ytd' : 3848.0},
          'NYSUI': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NYSUR': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'SS': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 2480.0, 'ytd' : 2480.0},
          'SS-R': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 2480.0, 'ytd' : 2480.0},
         }
},
{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 1,
'check_date' : '01/21/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': {'ctd' : 500.0, 'qtd' : 10500.0, 'ytd' : 10500.0},
          'FUTA': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'MED': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 1160.0, 'ytd' : 1160.0},
          'MED-R': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 1160.0, 'ytd' : 1160.0},
          'MEDADD': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NY': {'ctd' : 3848.0, 'qtd' : 7696.0, 'ytd' : 7696.0},
          'NYSUI': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NYSUR': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'SS': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 4960.0, 'ytd' : 4960.0},
          'SS-R': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 4960.0, 'ytd' : 4960.0},
         }
},
{
'employee' : 1,
'quarter' : 2,
'check_date' : '04/04/14',
'taxes': {'FITW': {'ctd' : 500.0, 'qtd' : 500.0, 'ytd' : 11000.0},
          'FUTA': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'MED': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 580.0, 'ytd' : 1740.0},
          'MED-R': {'ctd' : 580.0, 'qtd' : 580.0, 'ytd' : 1740.0},
          'MEDADD': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NY': {'ctd' : 3848.0, 'qtd' : 3848.0, 'ytd' : 11544.0},
          'NYSUI': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'NYSUR': {'ctd' : 0.0, 'qtd' : 0.0, 'ytd' : 0.0},
          'SS': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 2480.0, 'ytd' : 7440.0},
          'SS-R': {'ctd' : 2480.0, 'qtd' : 2480.0, 'ytd' : 7440.0},
         }
}]
```

I figure this is the most appropriate resulting structure for convenience. However, if there is a better way or some other solution that allows for easy access to the ctd, qtd, and ytd values I would like to see it.

I have also considered using mongodb aggregation but it just seemed like pandas may be better fit for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: this helped https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1744

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post that does basically what you are asking for - with a few modifications needed:

http://josephmisiti.github.io/group-by-datetimes-in-pandas.html

Comment: you don't need to strip the time when you are resampling, FYI, that's the point of resampling by say 'D' it ignores the times.